# How to deal with work for free as part of hiring process when I already have a job?

Tags: job-offer, job-change, leave-of-absence, test, middle-east

It takes 1 to 3 weeks but I don't know what to do with my current job that I don't want to lose it, if I failed in the test. It's an on site test and the office is in my city. They told me it's about how you deal with our team and the test tasks that we assign to you.

I need to know how to deal with it professionally.

Comment: What country is this?  I've never heard of a multi-week pre-employment test.

Comment: Do you need to be at a specific location for 1 to 3 weeks?

Comment: @JustinCave Iran, everything is different in here!

Comment: @sf02 No, I should be in their office, and both of jobs are in the same city.

Comment: I guess you can't take a vacation?

Comment: @Daniyal a pre employment test doesn't guarantee you'll get the job, even if you ace it.  I wouldn't risk my current job with this unknown.

Comment: @AnneDaunted  I wonder if it's not professional, also I'm worry about my reputation because I'm living in a small city.

Comment: Is it a pre-employment test for a job you currently have, perhaps just started?  What kind of test? Drug test, skills test?

Comment: @thursdaysgeek They told me it's about how you deal with our team and the tasks that we assign to you. I'm a programmer.

Comment: This sounds more like a probationary period than a pre-employment test. If that is the case, editing the question will clear up a lot of the confusion that seems to be present.

Comment: Serious red flag here.  Run the other way.  Seriously.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I've never heard of a "pre-employment" test that involves you being on site, carrying out tasks for 1-3 weeks. The only pre-employment tests I've ever heard of outside of interviews have been tasks that can easily be completed outside of working hours, therefore without your current employer knowing, and shouldn't take more than an evening or two to accomplish (at a maximum.)

Seems like a red flag in my book. The rather odd, and disruptive nature of this is enough that if it were me, I'd just send a polite email declining the offer.

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like you'll be doing actual work for free.

Stick with your current company or find a better offer somewhere else.

Pre-employment tests should include solely short tasks that have been "done a million times" and are considered common knowledge within your profession.

That amount of work should only be agreed to if they pay you for your time as it most likely is not a test.

Let them know that you won't have the time to do such a lengthy test.
Either thank them for their effort and inform them that you'll have to regretfully decline or ask if they could arrange for a shorter test, depending on whether you want the job or not.